# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' while writing to a file.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable index whose structure is like :

```
{ ‘web’: [ [1, [0, 2]], [2, [2]] ], ‘retrieval’: [ [1, [1]] ], ‘search’: [ [1, [3]], [2, [0]] ], ‘information’: [ [1, [4]] ], ‘engine’: [ [2, [1]] ], ‘ranking’: [ [2, [3]] ] }
```

I need to write this in a file in following format

```
term|docID1:pos1,pos2;docID2:pos3,pos4,pos5;…
```

So, postings list pair `‘web’: [ [1, [0, 2]], [2, [2]] ]` would be saved as: `web|1:0,2;2:2`

This is the code i am using,

```
def writeIndexToFile(self):
    '''write the inverted index to the file'''
    f=open("indexFile.dat", 'w')
    for term in self.index.items():
        postinglist=[]
        for p in self.index[term]:
            docID=p[0]
            positions=p[1]
            postinglist.append(':'.join([str(docID) ,','.join(map(str,positions))]))
        print >> f, ''.join((term,'|',';'.join(postinglist)))

    f.close()
```

I am getting following error:

```
for p in self.index[term]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I am using python 3.4.

Comment: debugging 101: look at the content of the variables implicated in the issue (`term`, for starters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this will give you an idea on what you need:

```
index = { 'web': [ [1, [0, 2]], [2, [2]] ], 'retrieval': [ [1, [1]] ], 'search': [ [1, [3]], [2, [0]] ], 'information': [ [1, [4]] ], 'engine': [ [2, [1]] ], 'ranking': [ [2, [3]] ] } 

with open("indexFile.dat", 'w') as f:
    for k,v in index.items():
        row = "%s|%s\n" % (k, ";".join(["%s:%s" % (i, ",".join([str(x) for x in r])) for i,r in v]))
        f.write(row)
```

Which would create a file as follows:

```
engine|2:1
web|1:0,2;2:2
search|1:3;2:0
ranking|2:3
information|1:4
retrieval|1:1
```

Tested using Python 2.7, so will need some minor tweaking for your Python 3.4.

Comment: thanks, this works just fine with python 3.4. I was really getting hard time with print. yours way is good.

Comment: Great, glad it solved your problem, was not able to test under 3.4, but it looked like it would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

`dict.items` returns a list of tuples so terms  is a `tuple` containing the key and value pairings from your dict,  you are trying to use the tuple which contains a list as the key which because it contains a list is not hashable and you get the error.

If you want the key and values separately unpack:

```
for k,v in self.index.items():
   for p in self.index[k]:
```

But you only seem to be using the values judging by your attempt at `self.index[term]` so just use them from the start:

```
for p in self.index.values()
```

If the values all have two element you can also unpack:

```
 for k,v  in d.items():
    for doc, pos in v:
        print(doc ,pos)
```

Output:

```
1 [3]
2 [0]
2 [1]
2 [3]
1 [0, 2]
2 [2]
1 [4]
1 [1]
```

Comment: for doc,pos , its giving me error : ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack. for p in self.index.values() its giving error positions=p[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @saurabhagarwal,  edited, I meant the actual values from .items

Answer (score 1):

Tuple unpacking will help clean things up a bit here. When you have an iterator that returns two (or more items), you can unpack the values like so.

```
x, y = [1, 2]
```

You can also do extended unpacking, where you take the first item and separate it from the rest.

```
x, *y = range(10)
# [0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Also, Python 3 tends to use string format instead of "%s" type stuff (printf style formatting). No need to convert ints to strings before feeding it in.

```
'{}: {}'.format(1, [3, 4])
# '1: [3, 4]'
```

And last but not least, taking the printing out of writeIndexToFile means you can use it for other things. It's a good example of a generator-a function or method that returns one thing at a time.

```
def format_index(index):
    for term, position_ in index.items():
        posting_list = []
        for doc_id, raw_positions in position_:
            formatted_positions = map(str, raw_positions)
            positions = ','.join(formatted_positions)

            posting = '{}:{}'.format(doc_id, positions)
            posting_list.append(posting)

        yield '{}|{}'.format(term, ';'.join(posting_list))
```

Now you can use it with

```
with open('file.dat', 'w') as f:
    formatted_index = format_index(index)
    f.write(';'.join(formatted_index))
```